# Datastore permission denied when running bookshelf sample app locally

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am getting a PERMISSION_DENIED error when attempting to run the sample bookshelf app provided by Google CloudPlatform.

On https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-forms it says to run the following command:

mvn -Plocal clean jetty:run-exploded -DprojectID=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]

The error I am getting is:

```
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@25e203e6{/,file:///Users/markfriesen/Documents/workspace/getting-started-java/bookshelf/2-structured-data/target/bookshelf-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,UNAVAILABLE}{/Users/markfriesen/Documents/workspace/getting-started-java/bookshelf/2-structured-data/target/bookshelf-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:128)
...
Caused by: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Missing or insufficient permissions., code=PERMISSION_DENIED
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:126)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:169)

I am able to launch the datastore emulator using the command: 
   gcloud beta emulators datastore start --project=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]
```

I am running:
  macOS Sierra
  Java version: 1.8.0_112

Anyone got ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it appears that the code is in fact connecting to the real GCD, not the Emulator, and you do not have the Datastore API enabled for the project. I would recommend logging into GCD and enable the Datastore API and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in a docker context :

- I was running the datastore emulator in a docker container within a docker-compose network
- I was trying to connect to it from my local machine.

When I ran the command/script from another container connected to the network of the datastore it worked. I guess it's the localhost exception or something like that.